# Does Qt application require addional libraries from end-user? Like C# and .NET Framework?

Tags: c++, qt, frameworks, requirements

I'm moving my game launcher & updater from C# to another language and framework because C# requires .NET Framework (a lot of players have problems with installation and stuff).

Does Qt require some additional libraries that user must install before he can run my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Even with static linking of Qt, on Windows you will minimally need the msvc (or mingw) runtime. (Often the end user will already have it, but you can't rely on that.)

You can read about the specific dependencies for each platform here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html#platform-specific-notes .

Comment: Well, if you follow he link, it does state that static linking is possible. Not desirable, though. Furthermore, "installation" of the MSVC runtime is as simple as putting those DLLs in the same dir as your EXE.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the QT runtime...............................